# markdown display picture well locally but not in browser

Tags: markdown

My issue is like that:
I insert some pictures in the markdown file. It displays well in VSCode preview, but don't display when I upload it to sharepoint.

I tried both the two types as below.
Please refer to code here:

```
![ValueCAN4-2](DPS/Intrepid_ValueCAN4_2.png)
---
---
<img src="DPS/Intrepid_ValueCAN4_2.png">
***
```

Refer to the display

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you also update the image in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I upload all the folders totally. Finally, I change to use OneNote instead. Our company's share point doesn't support markdown file.